# Specs2: skip inherited test suite

Tags: scala, specs2

In specs2, given the following code:

```
import org.specs2.mutable.SpecificationWithJUnit

trait TestSuite extends SpecificationWithJUnit {
...
}

class ConcreteTest extends TestSuite {
  // want to skip the whole test suite here
}
```

How in concrete test implementation of a test suite, to skip the whole suite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

```
import org.specs2.mutable.SpecificationWithJUnit

trait TestSuite extends SpecificationWithJUnit {
...
}

class ConcreteTest extends TestSuite {
  skipAll
}
```

Reference: [ArgumentsShortcuts](https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/blob/08d873b4bd1d0e3eec04dc7611f9d3afcb38cf33/common/shared/src/main/scala/org/specs2/main/ArgumentsShortcuts.scala#L35)

```
  /**
   * shortcut to skip all examples
   */
  def skipAll: Arguments = args(skipAll = ArgProperty(true))
```

This trait is transitively inherited to `SpecificationWithJunit` via the path: `SpecificationWithJunit -> Specification -> SpecificationLike -> SpecificationCreation -> ArgumentsShortcuts`

Comment: sure, will elaborate